# Peer authentication failed for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-12

I am using PostgreSQL-12 with ruby 2.7 & rails 6.0.3 on  ubuntu desktop 20.04LTS

whenever I try to `rails db:create` i get the following error

`FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
    Couldn't create the 'myap_development' database. Please check your configuration.
    rails aborted!
    ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

i have been tweaking the methods in **pg_hba.conf** from **peer** to **md5**, **trust**, all to no avail
my **database.yml** configuration is accurate too.

**databse.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  port: 5432
  password: postgres

  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myap_development
```

Comment: have you run `sudo service postgresql restart` after `pg_hba.conf` change? Can you add your `database.yml`config here?

Comment: i did run that code after that but did not do

Comment: try adding `host: localhost` to `database.yml`.

Comment: i have added `host: localhost` but didn't do

Comment: even now when i try to enter **PostgreSQL console**  like `sudo -u postgres psql` i get the following error `psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: my bad. i had to start the database sever  `sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start`

Answer (score 0):

Start database server

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
```